# Dial up numbers which contains #

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I’m creating an app for Android, where I need to send in commands which contains phone numbers and commands.

The code below works fine, when I’m passing in a normal phone number - It dials up the number as it should. But I need to pass in numbers like #200 with  # as the first number, used for call forwarding commands.

But when I’m adding a command which starts with #, nothing happens.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Code:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + callCommand.Command);

var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
callIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

StartActivity(callIntent);

_callCommandGateway.Update(callCommand);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Uri.Encode` the phone number that contains `#`s:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + Android.Net.Uri.Encode(callCommand.Command));
```